# Xubuntu doesn’t start

Tags: kernel

My computer wasn’t connecting to my Ethernet earlier so I tried resetting it. When doing so it reset instantaneously which is weird for my computer. I tried shutting down, but it just went right back on. I tried force restarting it with my reset button and it went off. When turning back on, it stayed at a black screen for a long time. I held down my power button to shut it down forcefully. Now when I turned it on it is stuck at “kernel panic”.

I have tried booting into safe mode to no avail. Reinstalling is not an option.

I’m using the most recent version of xubuntu.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by booting into an older version of the kernel in GRUB.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching to a new kernel version. Enter a plain-text terminal via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> at the black screen. Login, and run:

```
sudo apt remove linux-image-4.13.0-41-generic linux-image-extra-4.13.0-41-generic linux-headers-4.13.0-41-generic
```

Then run:

```
sudo apt install linux-image-4.16.8-generic linux-image-extra-4.16.8-generic linux-headers-4.16.8-generic
```

This should fix the issue.

Comment: I am unable to get back to that black screen after the first time I got there. Now, no matter what, I get the kernel panic. I can get to a command line from the GNU GRUB menu, but it doesn’t have any commands like apt.

Comment: @djitravz Can you get an Ubuntu live usb? If so, you can chroot into your install and then run the commands. To do the chroot, first get the live usb running, run sudo fdisk -l, find your hard drive, and then run sudo chroot /dev/sdx

Comment: This is what happens when I try to boot from the live USB. I try clicking ctrl+alt+f3 also, but it just clears the terminal. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1W2McY9FTuRHKP674f_6wAVJtgDKrmeNW/view?usp=sharing